# grabbing an image from an array with specific src attribute

Tags: javascript

i am new to js.
i am trying to grab a image from an array with similar class names which 
has a specific `src` saved in a variable `bigImgPath`

here is my Updated Code..

```
  var moniqueThumbs=document.getElementsByClassName('moniqueThumbs'); // Grab the ThumbNails
var bigImagesList=document.getElementsByClassName('monique-image');  // Grabs All Big Images

var currentBigImg='';

var currentBigImageFilePath="";  // Current Big Image path Captured by current Thumb Click //s
for(var i = 0; i <  moniqueThumbs.length; i++){
     moniqueThumbs[i].addEventListener("click", grabBigImgPath); // Added a myFunction Click event to Thumbs
    }




        // Grab Big Image Path from Clicked Thumb
        function grabBigImgPath() 
        {
    currentBigImageFilePath=this.getAttribute('data-bigImgPath'); // grabs the current bigPath from the thumb//

    var currentBigImageToDisplay;
    for (var i = 0; i < bigImagesList.length; i++)
    {
        if (bigImagesList[i].getAttribute('src') == currentBigImageFilePath)
        {
            currentBigImageToDisplay = bigImagesList[i];
            console.log(currentBigImageToDisplay);

            break;
        }
    }


}
```

**Still not displaying the current image in console.log**

Comment: could you please show your array

Comment: var bigImagesList=document.getElementsByClassName('monique-image');  // Grabs All Big Images

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `getAttribute` method to get the src:

```
currentBigImageToDisplay = bigImagesList[i].getAttribute('src') == bigImgPath;
```

That's still not right however, as it will just return true or false, so you want something like:

```
var currentBigImageToDisplay;
for (var i = 0; i < bigImagesList.length; i++) {
    if (bigImagesList[i].getAttribute('src') == bigImgPath) {
        currentBigImageToDisplay = bigImagesList[i];
        break;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could use the `filter` syntax:

```
bigImagesList = Array.prototype.slice.call(bigImagesList);
var currentBigImageToDisplay = bigImagesList.filter(function(item) {
    return item.getAttribute('src') == bigImgPath;
})[0]
```

[Working JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x7gqofk2/1/)

Comment: it says Uncaught ReferenceError: bigImageList is not defined

Comment: @MarcAndreJiacarrini Typo, should be fixed.

Comment: ok now i added  console.log(currentBigImageToDisplay); but nothing is shown in console... :(

Comment: @JamesBrierley iterating over a NodeList with filter is not possible. You have to convert the object to an Array first.

Comment: @MarcAndreJiacarrini I've added a working JSFiddle example

Comment: hey i am getting this error when i am adding your code to my code . The Error in console is Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input. What does this mean?

Comment: @MarcAndreJiacarrini can you include more of your code in the question?

Comment: @Hey see my question its updates. Still not showing correct result.

Comment: @MarcAndreJiacarrini Seems to be working for me (http://jsfiddle.net/x7gqofk2/2/).  The issue is probably with your html